# Identity Server v3 Custom Page Reset Password

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, identityserver3

I want to make on login page a URL that will redirect to http://server/resetpassword/ and there will be my cusotm page, made CustomViewServices from samples, but there is not example how to add your own page

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/CustomViewService

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not necessary to create a CustomViewService, you can deal with this scenario adding the following code in your AuthenticationOptions (in your startup class)

```
LoginPageLinks = new List<LoginPageLink>()
                {
                   new LoginPageLink()
                   {
                       Href = "resetpassword",
                       Text = "Reset Your Password",
                       Type = "resetPassword"
                   }
                }
```

in the logging page, there is the following code,

```
 <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li ng-repeat="link in model.additionalLinks"><a ng-href="{{link.href}}">{{link.text}}</a></li>
        </ul>
```

[More info here](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/configuration/authenticationOptions.html)

So using this customisation in your AuthenticationOptions, this will add a link to your custom page.

Then you need to add a resetpassword.html page in your the template folder.

Comment: any one has example of this? what model will it pass to resetpassword?

Comment: Where the page resetpassword.html should be create? Template folder, can you explain that?