# What is 'Type' property value in LoginPageLink?

Tags: identityserver3

I am using IdentityServer3 for authentication and I wanted to add external links on login page. something like resetpassword, forgotpassword etc. [For example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31046208/identity-server-v3-custom-page-reset-password)

I wanted to know valid values for `Type` property in `LoginPageClass` and how its been used? does it take any string value or these are predefined values?

Comment: Please stop forcing tags into question title, read the FAQ on how to properly use tags http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check the source:

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/blob/master/source/Core/Services/DefaultViewService/PageAssets/login.html

If you're using the DefaultViewService and the default views, no it's not in use. I'm guessing this was added because someone wanted to group links by a type when creating custom views for the DefaultViewService.