# How to configure resetpassword

Tags: identityserver3

I am using IdentityServer3 for authentication. Users are stored using AspnetIdentity framework. I wanted to provide reset password functionality to users. I want to provide this functionality in IdentityServer hosting application. I have gone through several posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31046208/identity-server-v3-custom-page-reset-password) [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/587) [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/517) and this what I have done so far:

1>I have created custom user service derived from `AspNetIdentityUserService`.
2>Created `resetpassword.html`  and put it in template folder.  ([documentation)](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/advanced/DefaultViewService.html)
3>It's not necessary to create a CustomViewService, so I added `LoginPageLink` in AuthenticationOptions and now the link is available on login page.
4>Created `ResetPasswordController`

```
public class ResetPasswordController : Controller
{  
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult ResetPassword(string username)
    {
       // call customservice here and reset password

        return View();
    }
}
```

**Issue**
when i click on the resetpassword link, i get error

> The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine
>   supports the searched locations. The following locations were
>   searched: ~/Views/resetpassword/Index.aspx
>   ~/Views/resetpassword/Index.ascx ~/Views/Shared/Index.aspx
>   ~/Views/Shared/Index.ascx ~/Views/resetpassword/Index.cshtml
>   ~/Views/resetpassword/Index.vbhtml ~/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
>   ~/Views/Shared/Index.vbhtml

I know why the error is, its because we don't have corresponding view in `Views` folder where MVC framework in looking for. My view `resetpassword.html` is in template folder. And that's the confusion. Identity server is using `Angular` to build its views.

If I decide to use angular then

> 1>How do I create and pass model to resetpassword.html.
>   2>How do I wire-up my CustomUserService to controller.

If I use ASP.NET MVC then

> 1>I need to add `resetpassword.cshtml` in `Views` folder and also a new `Layout.cshtml` in shared folder.
>   2>Doing so MVC scafolding will add bootstrap resources (css,js, jquery). The version may not match with IdentityServer's embedded resources.
>   I am comfortable coding ASP.NET MVC but worried adding bootstrap resources twice in the solution.

What is the best and easy approach here. Any sample example will be greatly appreciated.