# Identity Server 3 Reset Password Page

Tags: identityserver3

[Identity Server v3 Custom Page Reset Password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31046208/identity-server-v3-custom-page-reset-password)

I am doing the very same thing except I am working from the Mvc View Service example. I cannot figure out how I need to modify the `MvcViewService` and `LogonWorkflowController` to add the reset password page / view.

Any assist is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In `MvcViewService` class you have to change implementation of `public Task<Stream> Login(LoginViewModel model, SignInMessage message)` method.

Below code example adds two custom links to *Login* page:

- Reset password
- Register

```
public Task<Stream> Login(LoginViewModel model, SignInMessage message)
{
    model.AdditionalLinks = new List<LoginPageLink>()
    {
        new LoginPageLink()
        {
            Text = "Reset password",
            Href = "resetpassword"
        },
        new LoginPageLink()
        {
            Text = "Register",
            Href = "register"
        }
    };

    return this.GenerateStream(
        model, 
        message, 
        "login", 
        () => this.defaultViewService.Login(model, message));
}
```

This is how it looks:
[image: Login page result with two additional links at the bottom]